# Integrating Keycloak with Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, keycloak

I Use Alfresco in my spring boot Application. I wanted to use authentication subsystem(identity-service). i have given configurations to use in alfresco-global.properties.
It is not connecting to Keycloak. No errors found in log. I could find in logs Authentication subsystem starts though.

[  restartedMain] a.i.IdentityServiceDeploymentFactoryBean : Keycloak JWKS URL: http://localhost:8011/auth/realms/alfresco-dbp/protocol/openid-connect/certs
2019-10-24 16:41:34.956  INFO  --- [  restartedMain] a.i.IdentityServiceDeploymentFactoryBean : Keycloak Realm: alfresco-dbp
2019-10-24 16:41:34.956  INFO  --- [  restartedMain] a.i.IdentityServiceDeploymentFactoryBean : Keycloak Client ID: alfresco-client
2019-10-24 16:41:34.958  INFO  --- [  restartedMain] o.a.r.m.s.ChildApplicationContextFactory : Startup of 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed, identity-service1] complete

Comment: Have you configured, KeyCloak as Authentication sub-sytem? Possible share your configure details ?

Comment: authentication.chain=identity-service1:identity-service,alfrescoNtlm1:alfrescoNtlm
identity-service.authentication.enabled=true
identity-service.enable-basic-auth=true
identity-service.authentication.defaultAdministratorUserNames=admin
identity-service.authentication.validation.failure.silent=false
identity-service.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8011/auth
identity-service.realm=alfresco-dbp
identity-service.resource=alfresco-client
identity-service.public-client=true
identity-service.ssl-required=none

Comment: With the same configuration I am able to run in alfresco-community-6.1. In spring boot I use alfresco-repository version 7.9 with same configurations its not working

Answer (score 1):

Alfresco provides Identity Service for SSO. I have integrated Alfresco 6.2.2 with Identity Service 1.3. It is working fine.
But still if you want to implement standalone keycloak independently, it will work with same configuration. I have tested with keycloak 9.0.3 and keycloak 11.0.0 (which is the underlying version of Identity Service 1.3) - both integrated with Alfresco, and working correctly.

The configuration in alfresco files would remain the same :
Below are the alfresco-global.properties settings. Keycloak is assumed to be running on port 8081:

```
authentication.chain=identity-service-1:identity-service,alfrescoNtlm-1:alfrescoNtlm
identity-service.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8081/auth
identity-service.enable-basic-auth=true
identity-service.realm=sharerealm
identity-service.resource=alfresco
csrf.filter.referer=http://localhost:8080
csrf.filter.origin=http://localhost:8080/*

aims.enabled=true
aims.realm=sharerealm
aims.resource=alfresco
aims.authServerUrl=http://localhost:8081/auth
aims.publicClient=true
```

Entry in share-config-custom.xml file:

```
<!-- AIMS -->
   
<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="AIMS">
<enabled>true</enabled>
<realm>sharerealm</realm>
<resource>alfresco</resource>
<authServerUrl>http://localhost:8081/auth</authServerUrl>
<sslRequired>none</sslRequired>
<publicClient>true</publicClient>
<autodetectBearerOnly>true</autodetectBearerOnly>
<alwaysRefreshToken>true</alwaysRefreshToken>
<principalAttribute>email</principalAttribute>
<enableBasicAuth>true</enableBasicAuth>
</config>
```

If you are working with ADF or ADW (Alfresco Digital Workspace), then the following entry in app.config.json:

```
"$schema": "../node_modules/@alfresco/adf-core/app.config.schema.json",
  "ecmHost": "http://localhost:8080",
  "aosHost": "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/aos",
  "baseShareUrl": "http://localhost:8080/adw",
  "providers": "ECM",
  "authType": "OAUTH",
  "oauth2": {
    "host": "http://localhost:8081/auth/realms/sharerealm",
    "clientId": "alfresco",
    "scope": "openid",
    "secret": "",
    "implicitFlow": true,
    "silentLogin": true,
    "publicUrls": [
      "**/preview/s/*",
      "**/settings"
    ],
    "redirectSilentIframeUri": "http://localhost:8080/adw/assets/silent-refresh.html",
    "redirectUri": "/adw",
    "redirectUriLogout": "/adw/#/login"
  },
```